# How to set the line width of error bar caps

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can the line width of the error bar caps in Matplotlib be changed?

I tried the following code:

```
(_, caplines, _) = matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar(
    data['distance'], data['energy'], yerr=data['energy sigma'],
    capsize=10, elinewidth=3)

for capline in caplines:
    capline.set_linewidth(10)
    capline.set_color('red')

pp.draw()
```

Unfortunately, this updates the color of the caps, but does *not* update the *line width* of the caps!

The resulting effect is similar to the "fat error bar lines / thin caps" in the following image:
[image]

It would be nice to have "fat" bar caps, in the case; how can this be done, in Matplotlib?  Drawing the bar caps "manually", one by one with `plot()` would work, but a simpler alternative would be best.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is based on @joaquin's answer, but a little more concise (if you just want plain error caps with no special styling):

```
distance = [1,3,7,9]
energy = [10,20,30,40]
sigma = [1,3,2,5]

plt.errorbar(distance, 
    energy, 
    sigma, 
    capsize=5, 
    elinewidth=2,
    markeredgewidth=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 41):

EOL, you were very close..,

```
distance = [1,3,7,9]
energy = [10,20,30,40]
sigma = [1,3,2,5]

(_, caps, _) = plt.errorbar(distance, energy, sigma, capsize=20, elinewidth=3)

for cap in caps:
    cap.set_color('red')
    cap.set_markeredgewidth(10)

plt.show
```

[image]

`set_markeredgewidth` sets the width of the cap lines.

Matplotlib objects have so many attributes that often it is difficult to remember the right ones for a given object. IPython is a very useful tool for introspecting matplotlib. I used it to analyze the properties of the 2Dlines correponding to the error cap lines and I found that and other marker properties.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot!  We used the same method, but I somehow missed `set_markeredgewidth`. :)  So, the caps are actually markers, for Matplotlib, as opposed to 2D lines.  It seems to me that the `capsize` argument of `errorbar()` is equivalent to the `cap.set_markersize()`, so the latter could be removed, no?

Comment: While you were commenting I was also realizing that. I changed also the picture.

Comment: @joaquin, how do you use iPython for "introspecting matplotlib." This sounds like a very useful skill.

Comment: @William IPython with the option --pylab, sets an environment with the conditions to plot interactively with matplotlib. At the same time you can <TAB> at any `object.` to list its methods and check the docs of selected ones with `object.method?`. In this way you can check *in vivo* how changes in a given property affects your figure.

Comment: i'm not seeing how to do this when plotting a bar graph with errorbars using `bar`.