# Matplotlib Errorbar Caps Missing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to create a scatter plot with errorbars in matplotlib. The following is an example of what my code looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

x = np.linspace(1,2,10)
y = np.linspace(2,3,10)
err = [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(10)]

plt.errorbar(x, y,
       yerr=err,
       marker='o',
       color='k',
       ecolor='k',
       markerfacecolor='g',
       label="series 2",
       capsize=5,
       linestyle='None')
plt.show()
```

The problem is the plot which is output contains no caps at all! [image]

For what it's worth, I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.6.1 (64-bit)|, and Matplotlib 1.2.1.

Could this be a hidden rcparam that needs to be overwritten?

Comment: did you change anything to make your background gray?  I am wondering if you are having zorder issues (related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003572/how-to-force-errorbars-to-render-last-with-matplotlib/14007175#14007175).  The patch for that issue is in 1.3, but not 1.2.1

Comment: Your code runs correctly on my system, I suspect that in making the graphs look awful (yes, I know it is subjective) you broke something.  We need to see your rcparams to debug this.

Comment: Yes, Actually I am using a matplotlibrc file which is significantly altered from what it is by default. What section of the file are you needing to look at?

Comment: does this work as expected if you use the default `matplotlibrc` file (just rename yours before you start up python)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What worked for me was adding this (as per: [How to set the line width of error bar caps, in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601334/how-to-set-the-line-width-of-error-bar-caps-in-matplotlib)):

```
(_, caps, _) = plt.errorbar(x,y, yerr=err, capsize=20, elinewidth=3)

for cap in caps:
    cap.set_color('red')
    cap.set_markeredgewidth(10)
```

Comment: Not particularly. I've tried to understand it, but it the syntax seems to be confusing me. I know (_,caps,_) is producing a tuple of tuples, however, set_color() and set_markeredgewidth() I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: They do exactly what they sound like, set the color and the the edge width of the markers.  http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_color  http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markeredgewidth

Comment: I was more asking did you figure out what you changed in you `matplotlibrc` file that broke it.

Comment: For me the main fault was for some inexplicable reason `capsize`. Instead of `set_markeredgewidth` and `set_color`, you should be able to use the `capthick` and `ecolor` arguments in the [`errorbar` call](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html).

Answer (score 18):

Slight simplification of astromax's answer:

```
plt.errorbar(x,y, yerr=err, capsize=20, elinewidth=3, markeredgewidth=10)
```

It seems that somehow markeredgewidth is defaulting to 0 sometimes.

Answer (score 16):

It has to do with the rcParams in matplotlib. To solve it, add the following lines at the beginning of your script:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'errorbar.capsize': 2})
```

It also works with `plt.bar()`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers referring to `markeredgewidth` work. There's a new argument now that is more descpritive `capthick` for *cap thickness*. From the documentation of version `3.7.2` of `matplotlib`.

```
capthick : float, default: None
    An alias to the keyword argument *markeredgewidth* (a.k.a. *mew*).
    This setting is a more sensible name for the property that
    controls the thickness of the error bar cap in points. For
    backwards compatibility, if *mew* or *markeredgewidth* are given,
    then they will over-ride *capthick*. This may change in future
    releases.
```