# Top and bottom line on errorbar with python and seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot errorbars with python and seaborn but I am not entirely satisfied with how they look.

The default seaborn error bars look like this :

[image: errobar default style]

But I am looking to add the bottom and top lines on the error bars like this (in order to differentiated between the two error bars, it's the default matplotlib style) :

[image: defaultmatplolib]

How can I do this in seaborn ?

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12))


x_values = [1,2,3,4]
y_values = [1,2,3,4]

y_error = [1,0.5,0.75,0.25]

plt.errorbar(x_values, y_values,  yerr=y_error ,fmt='o', markersize=8)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `capsize` parameter should be enough, but for some reason You have to specify the `cap.set_markeredgewidth` for them to show up too.. Based on: [Matplotlib Errorbar Caps Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434492/matplotlib-errorbar-caps-missing).

```
(_, caps, _) = plt.errorbar(
    x_values, y_values, yerr=y_error, fmt='o', markersize=8, capsize=20)

for cap in caps:
    cap.set_markeredgewidth(1)
```

returns:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The top and bottom lines on an errorbar are called *caps*.

To visualize them, just set `capsize` to a value bigger 0, which is the default value:

```
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=stds, capsize=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams.update({'lines.markeredgewidth': 1})
```

Adding the third line solved it for me.

It might be interesting to check for other rcParams settings as well: Look up the desired stylelib/style.mplstyle file in the subdirectories of your python installation. For my system this is in "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/". The markeredgewidth defaults to 0 for seaborn.