# pyplot change y-axis tick labels when using yscale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a semilog plot to base `e` and it looks like that. How can I get rid of the numeric rendering of `2.71...` and instead display it as `e`?

[image]

```
plt.figure()
(_, caps, _) = plt.errorbar(xarr, yarr, xerr=xarr_stddev, yerr=yarr_stddev, fmt='.', markersize=1, linewidth=0.25, capsize=1)
for cap in caps:
    cap.set_markeredgewidth(0.25)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel(r"$t$ [s]")
plt.ylabel(r"$dV/dt$ [V/s]")
plt.yscale('log', basey=np.e)
plt.title('Decay')
plt.savefig("plot_1.pdf", papertype = 'a4', format = 'pdf')
```

(BTW the three lines of code in the beginning are for the error bar caps which were missing for me. Went after [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434492/matplotlib-errorbar-caps-missing))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to write your own [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) and use it for Y axis. Adding the following lines

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

def format_labels(x, pos):
    return "e$^{%i}$" % np.log(x)
```

to the graph and setting the formatter just above the `savefig` line:

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_labels))
```

lead to the following graph:

[image]